# How to post the result of this dropdown into an sql table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php   
    $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bce_db");
```

connection

```
    $query = "SELECT assignee_code,assignee_name FROM assignees";
```

getting data from the data base

```
    $sql = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){

        $select = '<select name = "select">';//dropdown created

        while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
          $select.='<option value = "'.$rs['assignee_code'].'">'.$rs['assignee_code'].'</option>';
         }
    }
    $select.='</select>';//dropdown ended..

    //I used the $POST method by linking it to other php page, but it returns undefined variable
    echo $select;
 ?>
```

How to post the value of the dropdown in table?

Comment: You'll have to show us the important part of your code (the code that handles the form - and possibility the `<form..` tag)

Comment: And from your comment: _'I used the $POST method by...'_. Note that in case you are trying to access the variables sent (by post) from the form, the correct usage is [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Unrelated, but `$select` is possibly undefined if `mysqli_num_rows($sql)` is falsy, causing a lone `</select>` tag to be returned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$select = '<select name = "select" onchange="location = this.value;">';
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

  $select.='<option value = "addtosql.php?id='.$rs['assignee_code'].'">'.$rs['assignee_code'].'</option>'; //you can change the filename addtosql into whatever you want
 }
 $select.='</select>';
```

addtosql.php

```
<?php
//Connect to db
$id= $_GET['id'];
// Insert $id into db
?>
```